# video.js is not loading/working in IE 9,10 or 11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, video.js

I have been trying to get videojs working on IE for a few days now and still can't get it to work. All I have done up to this point is follow the general setup instructions in their documentation [here](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/guides/setup.md).

I am using the version 4.12.7 of videojs for this example. The following is the javascript I am running on body load:

```
videojs("example_video_1", {}, function(){
    this.src({ type: "video/mp4", src: 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4' });
});`
```

The html is as follows:

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png">
        <source src="" type='video/mp4' />
         <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
    </video>
```

I have tried loading the src attribute through setting it directly in the html and through the javascript, but nothing is working.

This same exact code works in Chrome and Firefox.

The errors that are generated in IE are below. I am running the video.dev.js file so I can read the code section that errors easily.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Anyone else happen to run into this issue and know of a fix for this?

Comment: Tested on EE11 - everything works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/brphwg8z/1/

Comment: wow...I try your jsfiddle and it still doesn't work for me. What version of IE11 are you running? I'm on 11.0.9600.17842 right now. Also, I got the same two errors when running your jsfiddle as well.

Comment: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/984

Comment: Thanks stdob, I will need to read through that and use the fix to see if that worked.

Answer (score 0):

The post above by [stdob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4989460/stdob) was the fix to my issue. Adding a try/catch around two sections of functions `canControlVolume` and `canControlPlaybackRate` allowed the javascript to continue processing and allow the videojs script to finish initializing. Thanks for the help stdob.

Link to the answer is [here](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/984).